# Android close system overlay window(Started from service) when back button clicked

Tags: android

I have opened a window(displayed on top of other activities) on clicking floating view(similar to FB chat head), how to close window when device back button is pressed. Below is my service code

```
public class ServiceFloating extends Service {

public static  int ID_NOTIFICATION = 2018;
private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView chatHead;
private PopupWindow pwindo;
boolean mHasDoubleClicked = false;
long lastPressTime;
private Boolean _enable = true;


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);

    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating2);


    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

    try {
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        // Get current time in nano seconds.
                        long pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


                        // If double click...
                        if (pressTime - lastPressTime <= 300) {
                            createNotification();
                            ServiceFloating.this.stopSelf();
                            mHasDoubleClicked = true;
                        }
                        else {     // If not double click....
                            mHasDoubleClicked = false;
                        }
                        lastPressTime = pressTime;
                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, paramsF);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            showOptions(chatHead);
            _enable = false;
            //          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            //          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            //          getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void showOptions(View anchor){
    windowManager.removeView(anchor);
    chatHead = null;
    View myView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.alert_layout,null);
    ImageView img1,img2,img3;
    img1 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.id_img1);
    img2 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.id_img2);
    img3 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.id_img3);
    img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"img1 Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    //params.x = 0;
    //params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(myView, params);

}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    //Restart the service once it has been killed android


    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 100, restartServicePI);

}
```

}

I couldn't add onBackPressed or a onKeyEvent methods inside the service. Please suggest a workaround. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You should handle your view only from activity and use communication components such service binding or broadcasts. You shouldn't create views from service, its not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my bubble will always be running(it's in service) so how can i show a view in activity on top of all other view when my bubble is clicked.